# Using De Moivre's formula for finding $\sqrt{i}$

Tags: complex-numbers

In class today, we learned about complex numbers, and the teacher described a simple procedure for finding the square root of $i$ in $z^2=i$. He explained to us to set $z=a+bi$ and square from there, which *did* work, but it took some work to get through.

Afterwards, he said that there *was* an easier way, and that was to use **De Moivre's formula** to find the square roots.

So...

> **Question:** How would you use **De Moivre's formula** to find the square root of any nonzero complex number?

---

I do understand that the formula goes something like this:$$(\cos x+i\sin x)^y=\cos(xy)+i\sin(xy)\tag{1}$$
But I'm not too sure how to apply that to$$z^2=i\tag2$$ for $z$ is another complex number.

Comment: Can you express _i_ in polar form - that is, in terms of cosine and sine?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the $n$-th roots formula (which is actually an equivalent version of [De Moivre's formula](https://www.encyclopediaofmath.org/index.php/De_Moivre_formula) )
$$
\sqrt{i}=i^{\frac{1}{2}}=(\cos\frac{\pi}{2}+i\sin\frac{\pi}{2})^{\frac{1}{2}}
=\cos(\frac{\pi}{4}+\kappa\pi)+i\sin(\frac{\pi}{4}+\kappa\pi)
$$
for any $\kappa\in\mathbb{Z}$. The above, for $\kappa$ even, gives
$$
\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}+i\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}
$$
while for $\kappa$ odd, it gives
$$
-\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}-i\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}
$$

For the general case, the formula for the $n$-th roots of the complex number $z=\rho (\cos \phi + i \sin \phi)$, is given by 
$$
[\rho (\cos \phi + i \sin \phi)]^{1/n} = \rho^{1/n}\left( \cos \frac{\phi + 2 \pi k}{n} + i \sin \frac{\phi + 2 \pi k}{n} \right), \quad k = 0, 1, \dots,
$$
$\rho$ is the modulus. For the square roots, just set $n=2$.

Comment: Okay, then how would you use it to find $z^2=2+4i$ for $z$ is a complex number? More generally, how would you use the $n$-th roots formula to find the square root of a complex number where its modulus is not equal to $1$. Could you please add that?

Comment: @Frank: I just did.

Answer (score 1):

$i$ has argument $\frac{\pi}{2}$ and modulus $1$, so by de Moivre's formula the number with argument $\frac{\pi}{4}$ and modulus $1$ is a square root of $i$.

Therefore the number $\cos(\frac{\pi}{4})+i\sin(\frac{\pi}{4})=\frac{1}{\sqrt2}+\frac{i}{\sqrt 2 }$ is a square root for $i$.

Comment: Think you are missing an $i$ in your answer.

Comment: also $\frac{\pi}{4}$ should be in the last line instead of $\frac{\pi}{2}$

Comment: right, thanks.${}{}$

Comment: @JorgeFernándezHidalgo Argument $\frac {\pi}2$ and modulus $1$?? What does *that* mean?

Comment: the argument is the angle formed by the line between the origin and the number ( in the complex plane) and the modules is the distance between the number and the origin in  the complex plane. How were you taucgh De-Moivres formula?

Comment: @JorgeFernándezHidalgo I was *never* taught De Moivre's formula! He just said "There are, in fact, easier ways to think about this than working through the Algebra. I'm referring to De Moivre's formula, if you've heard of it..."

Answer (score 1):

$i$ = $e^{i\frac{\pi}{2}}$, so $\sqrt i $ = $\sqrt {e^{i\frac{\pi}{2}}}$ =
$e^{i\frac{\pi}{4}}$